# Combinatorics Choosing Objects Under Condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, combinations

If 28 objects are arranged in a circle at equal distance from each other, in how many ways can 3 objects be chosen such that no two are adjacent or diametrically opposite.

Comment: Can you do it with 6 objects? with 8 objects? can you see how to generalize?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a tricky one.
We can solve this by first finding the total no of ways in which 3 objects are chosen . Then subtracting the total ways in which all 3 are adjacent , 2 are adjacent , no one is adjacent .

TOTAL NO OF WAYS IN WHICH WE CAN SELECT 3 OBJECTS = $\binom{28}{3}$ ways =3276

- when $3$ objects selected are adjacent , total cases $= 28$
- when $2$ objects are adjacent , total cases = $28\times 24 =
     672$, as we can select two adjacent pieces in 28 ways , then we can
  select the other in $28-4$ ways$= 24$ ways.
- when no adjacent , $2$ have to be diametrically opposite . this can be
  done in $14$ ways . now $1$ remaining can be selected in $22$ ways , as we
  cant select the two objects we have already chosen plus we cant
  select their adjacent objects thus total ways $= 14\times 22 = 308$

Finally, total ways in which the objects are either adjacent or diametrically opposite is $28+672+308 =1008$

Thus, your answer is $3276-1008= 2268$

Answer (score 0):

Let us fix 1 object. So we cant select 3 object thus selection has to be made from 24 objectz thus total ways are ${24\choose 3}.28/3$=

Comment: Are you sure you aren't double-counting some selections?

Comment: Ofc i forgot to divide by 3

Comment: $28{24\choose3}$ isn't a multiple of 3.

Comment: So what shud be the correct thing.

Comment: Have you looked at the other answer? Alternatively, there are 28 choices for the first, 24 for the second, but these 24 have to be split into cases to calculate how many for the third: we have to consider when the 2nd is 2 away from the 1st, when the 2nd is next to opposite the 1st, and when neither of the preceding.